# python logging basic how to use

Tags: python, error-logging

Python logging greatly helps me to create transcripts of background processing scripts.

I have so far used the basic configuration:

```
import logging
LOG_FILENAME = 'example.log'
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
```

as explained in the Python docs: [15.6. logging](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/logging.html). The nice thing of doing it this way is that you can use the line:

```
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
```

Throughout all your modules and classes without bothering with any of the logging configurations. Then you setup the logging in the main script to go to a file and all messages will go to that same file. Easy.

There is another way of doing the same, which goes something along these lines:

```
my_logger = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')
my_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
my_logger.debug('Test string')
```

Which is the same thing EXCEPT that you now have an instance to keep track of: my_logger. My modules and classes don't know how the logger of the day is named and having to pass another variable around would be cumbersome. I suspect I miss something very basic here, either my use of the logging module is faulty and only works thanks to some glitch or 2nd method must be very easy as well.

I want to switch to the 2nd method because that seems to be the only way to make use of additional features such as RotatingFileHandler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html):

> Multiple calls to getLogger() with the same name will always return a reference to the same Logger object.

So you could get away without having to pass another variable around.

Furthermore, loggers form a hierarchy:

> "loggers with names of foo.bar, foo.bar.baz, and foo.bam are all descendants of foo"

So the documentation recommends using:

```
logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

And in that way, organize the loggers in the same way you organize your modules.

Comment: Oooooh! That is magic, how does logging know that I have been there before?

Comment: Well, I am not sure of how it's actually implemented, but perhaps using some kind of static variable holding a dictionary with the created logs.

Comment: And what should I name my logger in order to keep using the modules as they are with the line -logging.debug("test")- in them?

Comment: I don't understand the question in your last comment. If you want to use the line you were using before then you don't need to write a name, right?

Comment: Well, I want to use the RotatingFileHandler so I have to get a logger with logging.getLogger('name'); but then I don't want to change my modules that have logging.debug('test') lines all over. Maybe I can get the same logger as the logging.debug logger. I tried logging.getLogger('root') but that doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, the other answer in this question states that when you just use "logging." then a default logger with a name "" (empty string) is used. Doesn't that work?

Answer (score 0):

In my projects, I typically define one `Logger` instance per module, `LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)`, and then just find-and-replace all uses of `logging.XXX` with `LOGGER.XXX`.

You don't actually need to use named loggers to take advantage of `RotatingFileHandler` and other features. when you do a plain `logging.info` call, it uses a default logger named `""` (the empty string). You can attach handlers to that logger like you would to any other.